# Implement Webclient Mono Caching

Tags: caching, spring-webflux

I am already implement a cache using a spring mvc application with Spring Cache and EhCache implementation where i configured (.xml) a key-type and value-type like this

```
    <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
    <value-type>my.object.returned</value-type>
```

However right now i'm developing a Spring Webflux application and i am calling a 3rd party API (Webclient call) to get some data.

What is the best way to implement cache (in memory) for Mono/Flux data returned from Webclient. Keep any Spring Cache strategy or Project Reator has some native caching strategy ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given any details of what you want to cache. Basically reactor has variety of `.cache()` methods for caching with different strategies. I'll give you some example of scenario when you need to get an access token for some API and make a call to that API with this token. Let's say, this token has expiration and we want to cache it and refresh after it's expired.

```java
/**
 * Creating cached token mono
*/
Mono<Token> tokenMono = authenticate();

/**
 * Flow for calling mock api with cached token
 * Mock api called every 3 seconds with token. Token is valid for 10 seconds
 * Token will be refreshed after it is expired
 */
@Test
public void cacheCallTest() {
    Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(3L))
            .flatMap(__ -> tokenMono)
            .flatMap(this::makeCall)
            .doOnNext(log::info)
            .blockLast();
}

/**
 * Mock auth api that returns cached token that will be cached until it is not expired
 * You can setup your caching strategy with .cache() methods, customize it with Duration and etc.
 */
public Mono<Token> authenticate() {
    return getToken()
            .cacheInvalidateIf(token ->
                    Instant.now().isAfter(token.validUntil)
            );
}

/**
 * Token supplier
 */
public Mono<Token> getToken() {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
        Instant validUntil = Instant.now().plus(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        return new Token("token " + validUntil, validUntil);
    });
}

/**
 * Call mock api with the given token
 * @param token token
 */
public Mono<String> makeCall(Token token) {
    log.info("Making call with token {}", token.getToken());
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just("Responded at  " + Instant.now()));
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Token {

    private String token;
    private Instant validUntil;
}
```

This will pring the following result:

```
02:55:46.723 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:55:56.710578Z
02:55:46.729 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:55:46.728161Z
02:55:49.704 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:55:56.710578Z
02:55:49.705 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:55:49.705182Z
02:55:52.706 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:55:56.710578Z
02:55:52.706 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:55:52.706181Z
02:55:55.704 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:55:56.710578Z
02:55:55.705 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:55:55.705420Z
02:55:58.711 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:56:08.711051Z
02:55:58.711 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:55:58.711654Z
02:56:01.702 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:56:08.711051Z
02:56:01.703 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:56:01.703090Z
02:56:04.706 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:56:08.711051Z
02:56:04.707 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:56:04.706760Z
02:56:07.705 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Making call with token token 2023-01-22T22:56:08.711051Z
02:56:07.706 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - Responded at  2023-01-22T22:56:07.706292Z
```

Pay attention to the timestamps of token while making calls.
Hope it helps.